# IE conditional comments working but tags visible?

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have the magnificent [HTML5 javascript shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/) linked to in my `<head>`.

It works fine **apart from** it displays the tags at the top of the page ie:

`<!--[if lt IE9]> <![endif]-->`

When I view source, it looks absolutely fine and dandy. I have absolutely no idea what is going on!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a space between `IE` and `9`.

Comment: I had the same problem because I'd typed ``if le IE 8`` instead of ``if lte IE 8``